# iOS - Run Pausing when creating a scroll view

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview

I am creating a scrollview in a separate tab in my app so that I can fit more controls on the screen. However, when I click on the tab, the run pauses with error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception '`NSUnknownKeyException`', reason: '`[<UIViewController 0x5b20ff0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]`: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key scroll.'

Any ideas why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does this mean? "'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: ... This class is not key value coding-compliant for the key X"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088059/what-does-this-mean-nsunknownkeyexception-reason-this-class-is-not-key)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your xib file you've connected something to a "scroll" property which doesn't exist anymore. Find this connection and remove it, and the error should go away.

Comment: The only thing I have, is the scrollview in the xib, and a IBOutlet in my .h file. When I remove the IBOutlet and therefore the connection, the error goes away but the view doesn't scroll. When I create the IBOutlet again, and connect it, the run pauses when I try to load the view.